# Plotting the solution of an equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, boundary-conditions

I just wondering if I can plot this solution?

```
   FullSimplify[Integrate[1/Sqrt[-1 + f/3 x^2 + b/x], x] , Assumptions -> {x > 0, f > 0, b > 0}]
```

Comment: Yes you can,try: `F[t_, f_, b_] := 
 NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[-1 + f/3 x^2 + b/x], {x, 0, t}]; Plot[
 F[t, 1, 1], {t, 0, 1}]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

(FE[x_, b_, f_] = Assuming[{x > 0, f > 0, b > 0},
    Integrate[1/Sqrt[-1 + f/3 x^2 + b/x], x] // FullSimplify]) //
 Short[#, 10] &
```

[image]

In this case, the numerous [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) expressions can be converted to radicals with [`ToRadicals`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToRadicals.html)

```
(FE2[x_, b_, f_] = FE[x, b, f] // ToRadicals // Simplify) //
 Short[#, 10] &
```

[image]

The `Root` expressions greatly simplify the expression

```
LeafCount /@ {FE[x, b, f], FE2[x, b, f]}

(* {728, 2445} *)

{FE[0, b, f], FE2[0, b, f]}

(* {0, 0} *)
```

The numeric approximation is

```
FN[t_?Positive, f_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] :=
  NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[-1 + f/3 x^2 + b/x], {x, 0, t}];
```

For specific values of `b` and `f`

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{FE[t, 1, 1], FN[t, 1, 1]}, {t, 0, tmax},
  PlotRange -> pltRng,
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05],
  PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed},
  PlotLegends -> Placed[
    {"Exact", "Numeric"}, {.2, .85}],
  WorkingPrecision -> 20],
 Row[{
   Control[
    {{tmax, 5}, 1, 20, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}],
   Control[
    {{pltRng, All, "PlotRange"},
     {{0, 7} -> "Fixed", All -> "  All  "}}]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: How to plot this Elliptic function?

Comment: It is plotted for the case `b == 1` and `f ==1`. For which values are you trying to plot?

Answer (score 1):

To make a plot you must define the constants: b and f. As MMA is not able to find an analytic solution, you may try a numeric one. Toward this aim,for an example, I set b and f to 1:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
b = 1;
f = 1;
tmax = 1;
sol[xx_] := NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[-1 + f/3 x^2 + b/x], {x, 0, xx}]

Plot[sol[x], {x, 1, 5}]
```

[image]